# Sequelize - Put aggregate function value outside of each result

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

tl:dr; - I want to pull out the average aggregate function result that gets included into every entry into a single separate value in my results set within Sequelize.

I've got a `reviews` table, and I want to grab an aggregate average of all reviews. I want to include this as a column in addition to the array of rows returned.

The raw postgres query is:

```
SELECT avg(rating) as average_rating
FROM reviews
GROUP BY rating;
```

In the ORM, my query looks like:

```
  const reviews = await Review.findAll({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id,
      status: STATUS_TYPE_ACTIVE
    },
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'rating',
      'body',
      'created_at',
      'updated_at',
      [
        sequelize.fn('AVG', sequelize.col('review.rating')),
        'average_rating'
      ]
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        attributes: ['id', 'photo', 'username']
      }
    ],
    group: ['review.id', 'user.id']
  });
```

which returns the values like:

```
  review {
    dataValues:
     { id: 2,
       rating: 5,
       body: 'testing',
       created_at: 2018-05-22T18:41:46.385Z,
       updated_at: 2018-05-22T18:41:46.385Z,
       average_rating: '5.0000000000000000', <--- here we are
       user: [user] },
```

As you can see, the `average_rating` is in there and looks fine. But I don't want this included for EVERY review entry that I get back -- just once.

I can easily transform the returned array (and pluck out `average_rating`), but I'd rather not mutate the items after they come back from the ORM. How can I do that?